# Isomorphism of two quotient groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be an abelian group and $p$ be a positive integer.  Let $ H = G/p^{t+1}G $. How to prove $ H/p^{t}H \cong G/p^{t}G $ $?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $p^t H = p^t G / p^{t+1} G$. Now use the [isomorphism theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Isomorphism_Theorem#Third_isomorphism_theorem).

Comment: How to prove $p^t H = p^t G / p^{t+1} G$ ?

Comment: This is obvious. Think about it for a while!